# can not Mockbean HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I can use @Autowired in controller like

```java
@RestController
public class Index {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @GetMapping("/")
    void index() throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("http://example.com");
    }
}
```

it works;

But when I try to test this class using @MockBean like

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class IndexTest {

    @Autowired
    Index index;

    @MockBean
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws IOException {
        index.index();
    }
}
```

it throw an exception and say

```
Description:

Field response in com.example.demo.Index required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69@425d5d46: a programmatically registered singleton  - javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse#0: defined in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I suggest not writing tests in the spring context. 1) It's clumsy and just too much effort for less gain. 2) Initializing Spring takes probably 10 times more time than actually executing the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although possible imho it is a bad habit of injecting the `HttpServletResponse` or `HttpServletRequest` like this. This will lead to weird issues and just looks plain weird aka wrong. Instead use a method argument of the type `HttpServletResponse` and use the Spring [`MockHttpServletResponse`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html) for testing.

Then writing a unit test is as simple as creating a new instance of your class and calling the method.

```
public class IndexTest {

    private Index index = new Index();

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws IOException {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        index.index(response);
        // Some assertions on the response. 
    }
}
```

If you want to test it as part of a larger integration test you can more or less do the same but use the `@WebMvcTest` annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Index.class)
public class IndexTest {

    @Autowired
    private Index index;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws IOException {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        index.index(response);
        // Some assertions on the response. 
    }
}
```

Or use [`MockMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) to test it with a mocked request

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Index.class)
public class IndexTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws IOException {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).
            andExpect(status().isMovedTemporarily());
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        index.index(response);
        // Some assertions on the response. 
    }
}
```

The test above can also be written using `@SpringBootTest` difference is that `@WebMvcTest` will only test and bootstrap the web slice (i.e. web related stuff) whereas `@SpringBootTest` will actually start the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

**First things first**: Junits are NOT written for controller.

Issues with the code-

1. Either you have multiple beans of `Index` type or you have multiple beans of `HttpServletResponse`. Both `@Autowired` and `@MockBean` check by type not name.
2. `HttpServletResponse` is more of DTO so it should be mocked using @Mock.

Comment: Depends on what you want to test. You can also write an integration test.